# Grid menu for application switcher

Tags: gnome-shell, application-switcher

I have been looking for a way to have a grid-like <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> popup menu in contrast to the default, single row popup menu.

The only extension I have found that alters the popup menu is [coverflow](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/97/coverflow-alt-tab/) but not in the way I want.

I use [Workspace Grid](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/484/workspace-grid/) for managing workspaces and it has the grid-like layout that I am looking for from the application switcher.

Does this feature currently exist?

#### future reference

[switchPopup.js](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/ui/switcherPopup.js) and [altTab.js](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/ui/altTab.js) should be the relevant for implementing this feature, and extensions [Workspace Grid](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/484/workspace-grid/) and [Workspace Matrix](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1485/workspace-matrix/), which I believe modify [workspaceSwitcherPopup.js](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/ui/workspace.js) and [workspace.js](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/ui/workspaceSwitcherPopup.js), should provide startup code.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, the activities overview gives a somewhat gridlike list. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> invokes it, but you can change it according to [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045829/how-to-change-shortcut-for-activities-overview).

Comment: I know about the activities overview. I have even wrote an application to open it with touchpad tap. What I didn't know is that it accepts arrow keys for navigation between windows in the same workspace. Figure out a way to make that extend for all work-spaces on all monitors and you got my check.